# Thingboard: Get asset ID from internal database

Tags: thingsboard

I'm using Thingsboard with Postgresql.
What I want to do is getting asset ID by direct access to internal db.

thingsboards's schema has asset table which has id field.  But it's id is different format from UI's.

`select id from asset;`
`1e8027e92ad5cd0b8faaf5b54912004`

Type of `id` is varchar(31), and it doesn't look like UUID.

But I want to get is `92ad5cd0-027e-11e8-b8fa-af5b54912004` from UI.

How can I convert to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ThingsBoard, for SQL databases, UUID is trimmed inside the database and **-** chars are removed.

Take a look at this util:
org.thingsboard.server.common.data.UUIDConverter

**fromTimeUUID**() -> transform UUID into String (this value you see in the Postgresql)

**fromString**() -> convert string to real UUID

```
public static UUID fromString(String src) {
        return UUID.fromString(src.substring(7, 15) + "-" + 
            src.substring(3, 7) + "-1" + 
            src.substring(0, 3) + "-" + 
            src.substring(15, 19) + "-" + 
            src.substring(19));
    }
```

Comment: How would you accomplish this in python?